# How to get rid of parenthesis when parsing list into numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am converting a list into a numpy array, but I get and additional dimension added to the new numpy array even though I am using

```
 data = np.asarray(data)
```

For example, I get this

```
array([[-0.21612032, -0.13234089, -0.0680606 ,  0.19915094, -0.0140476 ,
        -0.05581627,  0.08421431,  0.50645465,  0.29697838, -0.2453663 ,
        -0.16956885, -0.18547745]])
```

INSTEAD OF THIS

```
 array([-0.21612032, -0.13234089, -0.0680606 ,  0.19915094, -0.0140476 ,
       -0.05581627,  0.08421431,  0.50645465,  0.29697838, -0.2453663 ,
       -0.16956885, -0.18547745])
```

Comment: You can use `data = np.asarray(data[0])`

Comment: Simple fix. Thank you so much

Comment: You can also use  data = np.asarray(data).ravel()

Comment: what if they were multiple entries in the list and I still wanted to maintain them as separate entries in the array

Comment: You need to give an example of your 'what if'.  But first learn a bit about what those brackets represent in lists and arrays.  Then you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of such parenthesis you can use the np.squeeze() command: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html